# Loop through post member categories, check if desendant of x (by name)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Wordpress with WooCommerce, on the single product page I want to check if one of the product member categories is a member of a parent 'Brands' and if it is display the description from that brand member category.

I've done the following, however it outputs all the categories the product is a member of;

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
if($terms){
foreach($terms as $term){
$category_parent_id = $term->parent;
$category_parent = get_category($category_parent_id);
$category_description = $term->description;
//if(($category_parent = "Brands")){ // THIS DOESNT WORK OUTPUTS ALL CATS
if( "Brands" ==  $category_parent ){ // THIS DOESNT WORK EITHER, OUTPUTS NO RESULTS

$category_name = $term->name;
$category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
$image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail); ?>

Do Some HTML Stuff Here

<?php }
}
} ?>


Brands >
Brands > Brand1 >
Brands > Brand1 > Product
Brands > Brand2 >
Brands > Brand2 > Product
Brands > Brand9999 >
Brands > Brand9999 > Product
```

If 'Product' is member of 'Brandx' which is a member of 'Brands' then output the description from the 'Brandx' category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?php    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
            if($terms){ 
             foreach($terms as $term){
              $category_name = $term->name;
              $brand_lookup = get_term_by('name', 'Brands', 'product_cat');
              $brand_lookup_id = $brand_lookup->term_id;
              $brand_args = array('hierarchical' => 1,'show_option_none' => '','hide_empty' => 0,'parent' => $brand_lookup_id,'taxonomy' => 'product_cat');
              $brands = get_categories($brand_args);
              foreach ($brands as $brand){
               if($category_name==$brand->name){
                $category_description = $term->description;
                $category_slug = get_term_link( $term );
                $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
                $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
                echo $category_name; ?>

<h2>Some HTML funk here</h2>


<?php              }
                  }
                 }
                } ?>
```

Comment: Took another approach with it.  This works, would love to hear your revisions or if you have a better and more efficient approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

hi you just have a typo

```
if(($category_parent == "Brands")){ // THIS DOESNT WORK
```

that is why it's good to change a place to put the primitives to the left side

```
 if( "Brands" ==  $category_parent ){ }
```

Comment: When I change it to the suggested it displays nothing (No Match).  I think it maybe the '$category_parent = get_category($category_parent_id);' line that is causing the problem.  I THINK get_category is not acting as expected.

Comment: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string" This line if I echo it; $category_parent=get_category($category_parent_id); echo $category_parent;

Answer (score 0):

You should use "[get_term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term)" instead of "get_category".

```
$category_parent = get_term($category_parent_id, 'product_cat');
```

This will return term object so your "if" needs to look like this:

```
if ($category_parent->name === 'Brand) {
...
```

Comment: Same thing; Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Term could not be converted to string